# CSS/HTML a horizontal scroll bar appears when I load the webpage

Tags: html, css

So I'm messing with my sites CSS and all of the sudden there is always a horizontal scroll bar and my nav bar doesn't go all of the way to the end even though its width is set to 100%. Is this a common problem? I looked through my CSS values and none are enough to make the page need to extend.

Edit: Code

```
html {
 height:100%; 
}

.content {
    width:269px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
.home {
    width:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
    font: bold x-large verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-top:10px;
    }
.home a:visited {
    color: blue;
    }

.head {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px; 
    font: bold x-large verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

.foot {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 20px; 
    font: normal medium verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
body { 
    background-color: #FFF; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    font: normal medium verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}


div#navbar2 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: solid #000 1px;
    border-bottom: solid #000 1px;
    background-color: #336699;
    text-align:center;
}
div#navbar2 ul {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div#navbar2 li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
div#navbar2 li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 11px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}
div#navbar2 li a:link {
    color: #FFF:
}
div#navbar2 li a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
}
div#navbar2 li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #3366FF;
}
```

Comment: please push your code for better understanding

Comment: Something has overstepped it's boundaries

Comment: alright what would you like me to add?

Comment: Can you create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net which includes HTML markup?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4RQMy/2/ thats what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your footer has width:100%; but also has left and right padding

you always have to math paddings and widths.

edit: the same with your .head

Comment: Alright. I changed it to padding-top the problem still persists. or is that change no good enough? EDIT Never mind onjsfiddle it works but in chrome it doesn't i assume this is because of cookies or whatever chromes has

Answer (score 1):

to hide the stuff that overflows use: overflow:hidden;

Comment: do i just put that in the body? or which one

Comment: in the cssfile or in a style tag. by the other makeup for that div

Comment: use chrome or chromium and inspect the div that is overflowing

Comment: I'm on chrome and inspecting as we speak

Comment: you can aply it to the body and see what it does. but if you have a scroleble website(long) you can not do that

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css property to your body element style.

```
overflow-x:hidden
```

It will remove the horizontal scroll bar and prevent extra white spaces on the right for sure.